# ng2-admin dashboard issue while running application when i ran comman npm start

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on ng2-admin dashboard till yesterday i am able to run dashboard on my local environment, today i have taken latest code and run commands `npm install`, `npm start` and then facing below issue...

> '5ms chunk asset optimization  94% asset optimizationError in bail
>   mode: [default]
>   D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:6:0 Cannot
>   find type definition file for 'jquery'.
>
> asset optimizationError in bail mode: [default]
>   \ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:6:0 Cannot find
>   type definition file for 'jquery'.
>
> [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:6:1
>       Cannot find type definition file for 'jquery'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:7:1
>       Cannot find type definition file for 'moment'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:21:19
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Duration'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:22:17
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Duration'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:27:19
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Moment'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:28:18
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Moment'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:66:18
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Moment'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:66:57
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Moment'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:74:26
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Moment'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:154:27
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Duration'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:156:32
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Duration'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:157:27
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Duration'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:158:25
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Duration'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:159:22
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Duration'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:160:22
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Duration'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:178:52
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Duration'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:181:54
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Duration'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:188:46
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Moment'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:188:66
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Moment'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:193:29
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Moment'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:193:49
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Moment'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:200:26
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Moment'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:238:27
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Moment'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:239:25
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Moment'. [default] D:\ng2-admin\node_modules\@types\fullcalendar\index.d.ts:339:55
>       Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Moment'. [default] Checking finished with 25 errors
>       '

Comment: Firstly, did you declare `jQuery` in project? Another cause maybe version of some dependency not match with current version of others (need to remove `^` in version).

Comment: @Suraj, yes already mentioned jquery in package.json file, in dependancies portion,   "dependencies": {     "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.6" } and in devdependancies portion,  "devDependencies": { "@types/jquery ": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jquery.slimscroll": "^1.3.30" }

Comment: I think you meant Manh Le @Vinod.. can you share your tsconfig.json?

Comment: {  "compilerOptions": { "target": "es5",  "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResoluton": "node",  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true, "noEmitHelpers": true,  "strictNullChecks": false, "baseUrl": "./src", "paths": {}, "lib": [  "dom", "es2016" ],
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types"]  }, "exclude": [ "node_modules", "dist" ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": { "forkChecker": true, "useWebpackText": true
  },"compileOnSave": false, "buildOnSave": false, "atom": { rewriteTsconfig": false  }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root cause and solution for this problem,

- Root cause:
  They have updated some dev-dependency library versions in package.json file e.g. fullcalender, jquery, jquery.slimscroll etc. and while compiling they refer types as a ‘compilerOptions’ instead of ‘typeRoots’ which is actually referring to node_modules/@types.
- Solution:

  1. Delete below folders,
     Delete ‘dist’ folder under path 'ng2-admin\'
     Delete ‘node_modules’ folder 'ng2-admin\'
     Or you can run the command npm install, npm update.
     and make a below change in tsconfig.json file,
     ' "typeRoots": [
     "node_modules/@types"
     ]'
  2. Run command > npm run build:dev (to execute/run gulp file on local dev environment)
  3. finally run command, npm start and try to access the portal url.